# Show/Hide corrensponding between popovers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some buttons that generate popovers. Their class is `.btn-popover-link` . When I click I can see new form to be filled. There is also a button "Add different place". When I click it, I get some more fields to be filled, and I can click "Delete this place" and they hide again. When I click add new place on the first one, and then I move to the next, I ca't see "Add different place" button, in fact I can't see any button at all.

```
$('.btn-popover-link').on('click', function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.place-hidden-different').hide();
        $('.delete-different-place-btn').hide();

        $('.add-different-place-btn').on('click', function () {
            $('.place-hidden-different').show();
            $('.add-different-place-btn').hide();
            $('.delete-different-place-btn').show();
        });

        $('.delete-different-place-btn').on('click', function () {
            $('.place-hidden-different').hide();
            $('.add-different-place-btn').show();
            $('.delete-different-place-btn').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

That's probably because it remebers I clicked "add place" button, and so it hid. But how can this code be wrong? I understand that on every click, on every opening of next popover, all the functions can be executed, and so they are not connected between different popovers. Am I wrong? What can I do? I want to have every popover edited separately, that a person can add different place in popover no.1, but he decides not to in popover no.2 etc.

**EDIT**: HTML for that part:

```
<div>
                        <?= 
                        Html::button(Yii::t('app', 'Add new place'), [
                          //  'id' => "add-different-place-btn",
                            'class' => 'btn btn-success add-different-place-btn',
                        ])
                        ?>
                        <?= 
                        Html::button(Yii::t('app', 'Delete new place'), [
                         //   'id' => "delete-different-place-btn",
                            'class' => 'btn btn-success delete-different-place-btn',
                        ])
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="place-hidden-different">
                        <div class="place-name-hidden-2">
                            <?= $form->field($place, "[{$index}]name")->textInput()->label(Yii::t('app', 'New place')) ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="place-city-hidden-2">
                            <?= $form->field($place, "[{$index}]city")->textInput() ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="place-street-hidden-2">
                            <?= $form->field($place, "[{$index}]street")->textInput() ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="place-postcode-hidden-2">
                            <?= $form->field($place, "[{$index}]post_code")->textInput() ?>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
```

Comment: Please add relevant HTML.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Added :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't attach event inside event also you can't use ready function inside event try to put out the events and it use event delegation `on()` to deal with new elements added dynamically and `$(this)` to target the current clicked element and your code should works :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.btn-popover-link', function () {
        $('.place-hidden-different').hide();
        $('.delete-different-place-btn').hide();
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.add-different-place-btn', function () {
        $(this).hide();

        $('.place-hidden-different').show();
        $('.delete-different-place-btn').show();
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.delete-different-place-btn', function () {
        $(this).hide();

        $('.place-hidden-different').hide();
        $('.add-different-place-btn').show();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped, but only a bit. I still have problem, that I click on popover, click "add place", and when I move to next popover, and then come back, the are no buttons and place fields in the first one. It's a problem that I use classes, because when I click I affect all things with that class, but I can't give every button & field separate ID.

Answer (score 0):

[Zakaria Acharki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4281779/zakaria-acharki)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41722263/962603) almost got you there. The last part you need is that you do not want to hide all buttons and place, but just the relevant ones. I am assuming that the HTML in your question is repeated many times, correct? Let's say you give that `div` a class too, like `places-container`. You can then target `.place-hidden-different` and `.add-different-place-btn` only within that same container as follows.

```
$(function() {
  $('body')
    .on('click', '.btn-popover-link', function() {
      var $container = $(this).closest('.places-container');
      $container.find('.place-hidden-different').hide();
      $container.find('.delete-different-place-btn').hide();
    })
    .on('click', '.add-different-place-btn', function() {
      $(this).hide();

      var $container = $(this).closest('.places-container');
      $container.find('.place-hidden-different').show();
      $container.find('.delete-different-place-btn').show();
    })
    .on('click', '.delete-different-place-btn', function() {
      $(this).hide();

      var $container = $(this).closest('.places-container');
      $container.find('.place-hidden-different').hide();
      $container.find('.add-different-place-btn').show();
    });
});
```

The key part here is that, instead of selecting all elements with class `place-hidden-different`, we select them in the container. The container is found using [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then searching in that container only is done using [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).